# Access C drive using C++ programming

Tags: c++

I have a project that must hide a file into an image , first I used command prompt and it goes well. Now I am trying to apply this commands using C++ programming language, but each time it gives me that system can't find the specified path although it exists and work well using command prompt.

This my code:

```
system("cd\\"); \\access C
system("cd x"); \\X is name of folder in C
system("copy /b pic.jpg + file.rar NEWPICTURE.jpg");
```

This is the source of commands: http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Hide-Files-Inside-Pictures/

Comment: Didvyou specify the working directory?

Comment: Without the source code, we can't help much.  I'd venture a guess and say you need to add escape '\' to your code.  (Link for reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape)

Comment: Trying to hide a `.rar` inside a `.jpg`? That's not suspicious at all...

Comment: `system`  usually spawns a new process for each invocation. Consequently, `cd` in previous calls won't have any effect on the later ones.  You need to use just one `system` call to issue all these commands.

Comment: @PSkocik How can I add all commands in one `system()` , it gives me error in syntax!

Comment: I don't know about the Windows shell, but I'd try separating the commands with either newlines (`\n`) or semicolons.

Comment: If what you are doing is just typing shell commands, you don't need C++. You could just write a .bat file to do this for you. If what you want is to hide your commands, know that one can easily inspect the compiled .exe and find the command strings you are using. So "obfuscating" your code with C++ will not hide the commands at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you call `system()`, a new shell process is created to run that single command.  When that shell exits, its local context, including working directory and environment variables, is lost.  The next call to `system()` copies the context of the parent process (your program) all over again.

Your options are to pass a command list/pipeline to a single `system()` call, or to use functions that affect your own process context, such as `chdir()`.

Comment: how can I send it to a single `system()` call? @BenVoigt

Comment: @SarahMohamed: It depends on which shell you are using, but most support `command one ; command two ; command three`